# Cocomplete concrete category, morphism of sheaves on a space is an isomorphism iff every induced map on stalks is an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Reading Hartshorne, I had this question:

Suppose $F$ and $G$ are $C$-valued sheaves on a space $X$, where $C$ is a cocomplete concrete category. Is it the case that $\phi:F→G$ is an isomorphism iff each induced map from $\phi$ on stalks is an isomorphism?

Hartshorne’s proof assumes $C(A,B)^x=C(A,B)\cap Set(A,B)^x$, where $C(A,B)^x$ denotes the isomorphisms from $A$ to $B$.

What if we don’t even assume $C$ is concrete?

Thank you!

Comment: That is strange, that Hartshorne writes that $C(A,B)^\times=C(A,B)\cap\operatorname{Set}(A,B)^\times$, since there are many cocomplete concrete categories for which this is not true. (The standard example is when $C$ is itself the category of topological spaces and continuous maps; then this says that a homeomorphism is the same thing as a continuous bijection, which is incorrect.) But $C(A,B)^\times\subseteq C(A,B)\cap\operatorname{Set}(A,B)^\times$ would be correct.

Comment: There is a proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222896/a-property-of-a-sheaf-in-an-arbitrary-category (thanks to Alex Kruckman's answer for linking this). If I understand your question correctly, it is (other than the confusion from trying to understand Hartshorne's assumption) a duplicate of that question, so see if that helps you.

Comment: Hartshorne does not write this, nor does he talk about cocomplete concrete categories in general. He’s simply presuming that isomorphisms are precisely the bijective morphisms. Your observation that $C(A,B)^x \subset C(A,B)\cap Set(A,B)^x$, but not necessarily the other way around, is the motivation for my question.

Comment: This question and the [other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222896/a-property-of-a-sheaf-in-an-arbitrary-category) are different: the current question is asking about joint conservativity of the stalk functors, while the other one is asking about joint faithfulness. Also, of course, Hartshorne's assumption just means that the forgetful functor from $C$ to $Set$ is conservative. While faithfulness and conservativity are related, they are in general distinct concepts.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang :  Yes, you're right, thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In analogy with topos theory, we could say that the category $\text{Sh}(X;\mathcal{C})$ *has enough points* if your condition holds: For all $\mathcal{C}$-valued sheaves $F$ and $G$ on $X$, a map of sheaves $\varphi\colon F\to G$ is an isomorphism if and only if for all points $x\in X$, the induced map on stalks $\varphi_x\colon F_x\to G_x$ is an isomorphism.

The question of when a category of $\mathcal{C}$-valued sheaves on a space $X$ has enough points seems to be delicate. See Zhen Lin's answer here: [A property of a sheaf in an arbitrary category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222896/a-property-of-a-sheaf-in-an-arbitrary-category), and see [the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/point+of+a+topos) for information on the notion of a topos having enough points. Hopefully someone who knows more about this topic than I do can provide more information.

Comment: +1, this is good information. As someone who previously wrote a wrong answer to this question I agree with your final sentence. For others who are curious about a non-example of the mentioned property, there is an example of a topos with no points [here](https://sinhp.github.io/scribbling/22-11-2017-a-topos-without-points) which 
is fairly readable.

Comment: Depending on what $\mathcal C$ is, $\operatorname{Sh}(X;\mathcal C)$ may not be a topos at all. The linked nLab article is only about toposes (although the terminology ‘enough points’ is probably good terminology in any case).

Comment: Thank you, Alex!

Comment: Toby, I know nothing about topoi. If $C$ is cocomplete and concrete, is $Sh(X,C)$ a topos?

Comment: @TobyBartels Good point, thanks for pointing it out! I've edited. catagoricalimperative: If $X$ is the one-point space, then $\text{Sh}(X,\mathcal{C})$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$. So in general, $\text{Sh}(X,\mathcal{C})$ is not a topos unless $\mathcal{C}$ is.

Comment: @categoricalimperative :  A topos can be thought of as (among other things) a category of the form $\operatorname{Sh}(X,\operatorname{Set})$ for some $X$.  The most famous example is $\operatorname{Set}$ itself (which is $\operatorname{Sh}(X,\operatorname{Set})$ when $X$ is a one-point space).  More generally, $\operatorname{Sh}(X,C)$ is a topos whenever $C$ is (and Alex gave a converse to this).  This concept began with Grothendieck's work on algebraic geometry, but it's not central to algebraic geometry the way categories of schemes are, and it's taken on a life of its own far beyond AG.